# Windows SVN command line client not working with sublime text

Tags: svn, sublimetext3

I am trying to setup the windows command line client for subversion, I have got it working nicely and have set the svn_editor enviornment variable to the subl executable.

When I do a svn commit it launches sublime text with a commit log entry, however immediately the command line updates to say that no change was made to the log entry, before you can do anything in sublime text.

Even if I save the commit log it still makes no difference.

Has anyone any suggestions as to what I need to change?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: Try changing the command to `subl -w`.

Comment: Hi @MattDMo great that works, please put it as an answer so I can mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [command line documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html), the `-w` option for the `subl` command instructs Sublime to wait for the files to be closed before returning. This will allow you to enter your commit message.